# Set /p in a loop?

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop, input, set

This is probably impossible, but I have a loop that displays a animated logo by using `TYPE` to type `logo_(framenumber).txt` and the `framenumber` is determined by a loop:

```
:s
if %m%==379 set m=0
cls
TYPE Logo_%m%.txt
set /a m=%m%+1
goto s
```

I wanted to be able to use a set `/p` option and without disturbing/stopping the loop so the animation plays while a user is typing in the set `/p` input. I think there is a way to do it with `FOR` but I'm not sure how. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although this topic is somewhat old, I just discovered it. This is a pure Batch file solution that works pretty well:

**EDIT**: I slightly modified the code in order to made it simpler.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if "%1" equ "Animate" goto %1

for /F %%a in ('echo prompt $H ^| cmd') do set "BS=%%a"
for /F %%a in ('copy /Z "%~F0" NUL') do set "CR=%%a"
cd . > input.txt
start "" /B "%~F0" Animate

set "input="
:nextKey
   set "key="
   for /F "delims=" %%K in ('xcopy /W "%~F0" "%~F0" 2^>NUL') do if not defined key set "key=%%K"
   if "!key:~-1!" equ "!CR!" goto endInput
   if "!key:~-1!" equ "!BS!" (
      if defined input set "input=%input:~0,-1%"
   ) else (
      set "input=%input%!key:~-1!"
   )
   set /P "=%input%" > input.txt < NUL
goto nextKey
:endInput
del input.txt
echo/
echo/
echo Input read: "%input%"
goto :EOF


:Animate
set "banner=                              Enter your name please                              "
set m=0
:loop
   if not exist input.txt exit
   set /A m=(m+1)%%51
   cls
   echo/
   echo/     !banner:~%m%,31!
   echo/
   echo/
   if exist input.txt (type input.txt) else exit
   ping -n 1 -w 300 localhost > NUL
   ping -n 1 -w 300 localhost > NUL
   ping -n 1 -w 300 localhost > NUL
goto loop
```

In this solution the animated "logo" is replaced by a banner, but the method to display a series of files is practically the same.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: This is possible in batch. See Aacini's answer.**

<s>This is not possible with batch files. Batch commands are single-threaded.  To run two things simultaneously requires two instances of cmd.exe.  But the console subsystem only allows one program to own the console at a time, so if the second instance of cmd is attached to the same console, one of them must be blocked.</s>

It is possible to do something like this with a win32 executable which uses [`WriteConsoleOutput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to modify the characters on the console screen.  If you do that, you are no longer limited to just dumping text files, but the downside is that it's a lot more work than calling `type` in batch.

Comment: You should read the description of `start` command, particularly the `/B` switch. See my answer below...