# how to exit a loop with a keystroke

Tags: loops, batch-file

I have a script that searches for a running process (notepad) and it will stay runnning until notpad is no longer running:

```
:search
TASKLIST|FIND "notepad.exe" >nul 2>&1
IF %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 (GOTO found)
timeout 3 > nul
GOTO search

:found
exit
```

What i'd like to insert here is a prompt for keypress to exit this loop and jump to `:found`If no keypress is entered the file keep looking for notepad until it closes.

Comment: Type `waitfor /?` Instead of `timeout` use `waifor /t 3 cat`. When you kill it send in another batchfile `waitfor /si cat`.

Comment: @Mark what is cat?

Comment: A signal. I had to think of a word. I choose cat. Make it dog. In help they use `CopyDone` as an example.. If you create a shortcut to the second batch you can assign a hotkey in Properties.

Comment: thanks but I am not looking to make a second batch file. I simply want to be able to interrupt the script above with a keystroke if that is possible.

Comment: Ctrl+C interrupts batchfiles.

Comment: See duplicate question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61754467/12343998)

Comment: Nice idea to use `waitfor`, @Mark! you don't even have to use a second batch file, you can let a batch file call itself in a new `cmd` instance (similar to the answer user @T3RR0R linked to), so one instance waits and the other one sends the signal…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I corrected your logic a bit (to match `stay running until notepad is no longer running`)

```
:search
TASKLIST|FIND "notepad.exe" >nul 2>&1
IF errorlevel 1 GOTO :cont
choice /c cn  /t 3 /d n /n /m "[C]ancel"
if errorlevel 2 goto :search
echo you cancelled.
goto :eof

:cont
echo Notepad has closed.
exit /b
```

For an explanation of the `choice` command see `choice /?`
For an explanation of the changed `if errorlevel` syntax, see `if /?`

or - if you don't like the continuous `[C]ancel` - suppress the output of `choice` and print the hint before the loop:

```
echo [C]ancel
:search
TASKLIST|FIND "notepad.exe" >nul 2>&1
IF errorlevel 1 GOTO :cont
choice /c cn  /t 3 /d n >nul
if errorlevel 2 goto :search
echo you cancelled.
goto :eof

:cont
echo Notepad has closed.
exit /b
```

Comment: works perfectly. Wondering how I might replace C to cancel with ENTER?

Comment: nope. `choice` supports [a-z], [A-Z], [0-9] and ASCII between 128 and 254. If you really need "ENTER" (or "AnyKey") there is an ugly `xcopy` hack (not recommended unless absolutely necessary. You can extract it from [here](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4741))

Comment: ok thanks. Is there another way instead of using `choice` to jump out of a loop using `ANYKEY` or `ENTER`? Is this worthy of a new question?

Comment: If you find a promising way and just can't quite make it work, yes, ask another question. If not, it's just a code request and off-topic for this site. Did you take a look at the possible duplicate, @T3RR0R mentioned?

Comment: This solution is useful, but you could do away with a chunk of it by using the errorlevel with default timeout switches for the choice command with labels :0 and :1 - so long as you don't mind passing up on the cancelled / closed feedback

Answer (score 1):

The [`timeout` command](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html) waits for the specified time and can be terminated by a key-ress, given that the option `/NOBREAK` is not specified. It outputs a text like `Waiting for 3 seconds, press a key to continue ...` and updates the seconds value each second by placing the cursor right to the number, then writing out as many backspace characters as needed and then overwriting the number. This whole text, including the backspaces, can be captured by a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) and then checked for the last number being `0`; if it is not, the user pressed a key, aborting the `timeout` command.

This is how this approach could be coded:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Retrieve the backspace character:
for /F %%B in ('prompt $H ^& for %%B in ^(.^) do rem/') do set "_BS=%%B"

:SEARCH
rem // Improved filtering for the process:
tasklist /FI "ImageName eq notepad.exe" | find "=" > nul
if not ErrorLevel 1 goto :FOUND
rem /* Use `timeout` without `/NOBREAK` option to allow abortion of the waiting;
rem    `timeout` counts down the seconds and precedes each number with backspace
rem    characters, and the whole output string is captured by `for /F`; when no
rem    key is pressed, then seconds reach `0`, otherwise not: */
for /F "delims=" %%T in ('timeout /T 3') do set "TOUT=%%T"
rem /* Now let us replace each backspace by `" "` and surround the whole string
rem    with `""`, so we get space-separated quoted strings:
call set TOUT="%%TOUT:%_BS%=" "%%"
rem // Loop through those strings and assign each to the same variable:
for %%T in (%TOUT%) do set "TOUT=%%~T"
rem // The last string is now checked against `0`; if it is, no key was pressed:
if "%TOUT%"=="0" goto :SEARCH
rem // This point is only reached if a key-press aborted the `timeout` command.

:FOUND
exit /B
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Windows 7, there is the [`waitfor` command](https://ss64.com/nt/waitfor.html) (thanks to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62166124#comment109948297_62166124)!) to send or to wait for a signal, optionally supporting a timeout, upon which the [`ErrorLevel`](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html) becomes set; `ErrorLevel` is cleared when a signal is received.
This could be used when there is another parallel process (initiated by the [`start`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) command to not wait until finished) that detects a key-press and sends such a signel then.

Here is how that approach could be coded:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Jump to label if first argument is such:
set "ARG1=%~1 "
if "%ARG1:~,1%"==":" goto %~1
rem // Define name of signal and related console window title:
set "_SIGNAL=KeyPress%RANDOM%"
set "_WTITLE=///%_SIGNAL%///"
rem // Actually run key-press routine in a new instance of `cmd.exe`:
start "%_WTITLE%" /B cmd /D /C call "%~f0" :SEND

:SEARCH
rem // Improved filtering for the process:
tasklist /FI "ImageName eq notepad.exe" | find "=" > nul
if not ErrorLevel 1 goto :FOUND
rem // Await signal at this point, establishing a timeout:
waitfor /T 3 %_SIGNAL% > nul 2>&1
rem // `waitfor` sets the `ErrorLevel` in case no signal was received:
If ErrorLevel 1 goto :SEARCH
rem // This point is only reached if a key-press provoked the signal to be sent.

:FOUND
rem /* Kill key-press routine (other `cmd.exe` instance) if it is still running;
rem    since it is usually in `pause` state, its status might be `Unknown`: */
set "PID=" & for /F "tokens=2 delims=: " %%T in ('
    tasklist /FI "ImageName eq cmd.exe" /FI "WindowTitle eq %_WTITLE%" /FO LIST ^| findstr "^PID:" ^& ^
        tasklist /FI "ImageName eq cmd.exe" /FI "Status eq Unknown" /FO LIST ^| findstr "^PID:"
') do (taskkill /PID %%T || taskkill /PID %%T /F) > nul 2>&1
exit /B

:SEND
pause > nul
waitfor /SI %_SIGNAL% > nul
exit /B
```