# Batch file issue not solved

Tags: batch-file

I've tried to create an invisible countdown.
For example, the script starts the countdown, but in the meantime the script runs like an MMORPG.  When you are entering an instance dungeon, it starts the countdown and you can walk etc. But when I do it with `PING -n 6 127.0.0.1 //Delay the script for 5 seconds`. I want the PING to run in the background and meanwhile the script goes on. I've got a response from Stephan but his code didn't work :(

Stephan's Code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM create a CarriageReturn:
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"

for /L %%i in (5,-1,0) do (
<nul set /p =King Albireo is spawning in %%i seconds...!CR!
ping -n 2 127.0.01 >nul
)
goto Main

:Main
@title Example: Countdown
cls
echo It works
pause
```

Can someone make this script so it is running in the background and meanwhile the script goes on.

- I know I used the same words over and over just to make sure everyone is getting what I am trying to say.
- BTW thanks Stephan for the code.

Comment: What in the script is left to continue if you run the ping in the background? Also, if you run the ping in the background, _the script won't pause_. I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Batch is more scripting than programming, so it's not supposed to do more than one thing at a time. It`s [possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31531517/2152082), but surely [not easy](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4741) to implement.

Comment: By the looks of what you are trying to do, you have the wrong tool for the job. Batch isn't what you want to be using for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with

```
start "" /b cmd /q /v /e /c"(for /l %%a in (5 -1 1) do (echo respawn in %%a seconds&>nul ping -n 2 ""))&echo RESPAWN"
```