# Is there a way to read stdin without blocking script's execution using a vbscript?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd, jscript, wsh

I am trying to find a way read stdin without blocking my vbscript's execution but still no luck.

What I want to achieve is the following (written in sh shell script):

```
for i in {1..3}; do 
    read input;
    echo $input;
    sleep 1;
    if [ "$input" == "done" ]; then
        echo "process done";
        exit;
    fi 
done
```

Tried the following in vbscript but script hangs in the first iteration waiting for `Enter` in order to proceed

```
input=""
for i=1 to 3 
   WScript.Echo i
   WScript.sleep (100);
   If WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream Then
      input = input & WScript.StdIn.Readline()
      If input = "done" Then
         WScript.Echo "process done"
      End if
   End If 
Next
```

Is there a way not to block my script while reading stdin?

Comment: I will refrase my question: Is there a way to read stdin on Windows without blocking a script's execution (script can be in cmd, bat, vbs or js)

Comment: short answer: no. You need to get keystrokes, not STDIN to do that.

Comment: here is a [Batch solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31531517/2152082)