# How to make a batch SET /P statememt not require an enter

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I'm making my own console based off batch because I want more then what cmd offers but have the key features that batch has.

One of the most important things is to prompt the user for the command:

```
:prompt
@echo off
title JDOS command line
echo.
echo.
SET /P command="%FDIR%>"
rem SECTIONS/COMMANDS
rem /I means the if statement is not case-sensitive. USE IT AT ALL TIMES!
if /I "%command%"=="add" goto add 
if /I "%command%"=="subtract" goto subtract
goto prompt
```

(This is just a small portion of all the options but you get the idea)

```
:add
title Calculator/Add
SET /P Add_A=Please enter the first number:
SET /P Add_B=Please enter the second number:
SET /A sum=%Add_A% + %Add_B%
echo The sum is %sum% 
timeout /t 10 >nul
goto prompt
```

But this is timewasting and sort of idiotic (at least in my opinion).

So, can I execute `goto add` without the user pressing `enter` ?

## Edit:

I'm thinking an approach similar to `CHOICE` but with the option to have more than 1 key be pressed (so for example instead of 1/2/3/4/ it would be restart/shutdown/lock/logoff/

Comment: Just a tip (unrelated to the question) use `rem` instead of `::` for comments, technically `::` is a label rather than a comment

Comment: I prefer :: (I have used rem though its not my style)

Comment: That's fine, however in certain cases such as comments inside code blocks, it will cause the program to malfunction, so it's better to get into the habit of using `rem`. More information about it [here](http://ss64.com/nt/rem.html)

Comment: How do you plan on knowing when a user is done typing?

Comment: 1. The user presses a key such as `Ctrl`
2. The word typed is equal to "subtract" or "add"

Comment: You want to enter a single digit, right? if so: ever heard of command `choice`? type `choice /?` in command prompt...

Comment: No, the choice command unfortunately does no good. (Lol, I thought the choice command was only used in MSDOS). :]

Comment: if things are totally stable in terms of user choices, could you not redirect the input from a file?  i.e.  **"mybatch < mypretyped_responses.txt"**.  I've done before, but sorry, long time since I've been on Windows.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31531517/2152082) should be adaptable to your needs.

Comment: Um.... I have no idea what dat does.

Comment: basically it uses a `xcopy` trick to get single keystrokes and assembles them to a  word. (it  shows an animated banner while it gets Input, but you can ignore that)

Comment: If you think it works, can you use it with my code for an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified my accepted answer at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28710020/set-p-in-a-loop/31531517#31531517) and adjusted it for this request. Here it is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "commands=add subtract"

for %%a in (%commands%) do set "com[%%a]=1"
for /F %%a in ('echo prompt $H ^| cmd') do set "BS=%%a"
for /F %%a in ('copy /Z "%~F0" NUL') do set "CR=%%a"

set "command="
:nextKey
   set "key="
   for /F "delims=" %%K in ('xcopy /W "%~F0" "%~F0" 2^>NUL') do if not defined key set "key=%%K"
   if "!key:~-1!" equ "!CR!" goto endCommand
   if "!key:~-1!" equ "!BS!" (
      if defined command (
         set "command=%command:~0,-1%"
         set /P "=.!BS!!BS!  !BS!!BS!" < NUL
      )
   ) else if "!key:~-1!" neq " " (
      set "command=%command%!key:~-1!"
      set /P "=!key:~-1!" < NUL
      if defined com[!command!] goto endCommand
   )
goto nextKey
:endCommand
echo/
echo/
echo command read: "%command%"
```

**Note**: The mechanism used in this method does not allow to insert spaces! This code should be modified in large parts in order to read spaces.

Comment: Sorry, but "doesn't work" does not serve to find the problem. Please, indicate what exaclty you type, so I can duplicate the problem... (I suggest you to enter "add", "subtract" and "other" and check the result).

Comment: works fine for me (for expected and unexpected "commands"). You eliminated the need for `Input.txt` - very nice. (I basically worked with `findstr /b "add subtract" Input.txt`, but yours is better ^^)

Comment: Just do this: **1.** Open a cmd window. You may double-click on the "C:\" icon or open Run (Window key + R) and type: `cmd.exe`. **2.** Navigate to the folder where the Batch file is: `cd folder1\folder2\etc`. **3.** Enter the name of the Batch file: `test.bat`

Comment: It works. Sorry bout the post, was on the wrong question :(