# Echo text after the set command in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Is there way to echo text after a set command? I have tried, but nothing seems to work. Here is my code:

```
@echo off
Echo Enter a website:
Set /p op="Https:\\"     ".com"
:: The ".com" would be displayed behind the users input.
if %op%==%op% goto Show
:Show
cls
Echo Website: Http:\\%op%.com
pause
exit
```

How would I get the .com to be displayed after the input? I would preferably like to have the ".com" frozen in one spot, no matter how big the users input is.

Comment: I think this will not work, neither with `set` nor with `choice`. Perhaps you should try to find a solution based on windows scripting host or powershell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28710020/set-p-in-a-loop/31531517#31531517) and slightly modified it in order to fulfill this request.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F %%a in ('echo prompt $H ^| cmd') do set "BS=%%a"
for /F %%a in ('copy /Z "%~F0" NUL') do set "CR=%%a"

set "op="
set /P "=Https:\\.com!BS!!BS!!BS!!BS!" < NUL
:nextKey
   set "key="
   for /F "delims=" %%K in ('xcopy /W "%~F0" "%~F0" 2^>NUL') do if not defined key set "key=%%K" & set "key=!key:~-1!"
   if "!key!" equ "!CR!" goto endInput
   if "!key!" neq "!BS!" (
      set "op=%op%%key%"
      set /P "=.!BS!%key%.com!BS!!BS!!BS!!BS!" < NUL
   ) else if defined op (
      set "op=%op:~0,-1%"
      set /P "=.!BS!!BS!.com !BS!!BS!!BS!!BS!!BS!" < NUL
   )
goto nextKey
:endInput
echo/
echo/
echo Website: Http:\\%op%.com
```

**EDIT**: *New method added (requested in a comment)*

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /A spaces=10, backSpaces=spaces+4

set "spcs="
for /L %%i in (1,1,%spaces%) do set "spcs=!spcs! "
set "back="
for /F %%a in ('echo prompt $H ^| cmd') do set "BS=%%a"
for /L %%i in (1,1,%backSpaces%) do set "back=!back!!BS!"

set /P "op=Https:\\%spcs%.com!back!"
echo/
echo Website: Http:\\%op%.com
```

Comment: Thanks! It works like a charm. I just have one more question. How would you change the code so that the _.com_ would be frozen in one spot on the page?

Comment: Do you want that the `.com` part remains in a fixed place? How many characters after the `Http:\\ ` part? What happen if the input is too long that reaches it? Note that this is an _entirely different_ request!

Comment: Yes. i would like the .com to stay in a fixed place 10 spaces away from the `Http:\\`. For right now I don't need to worry about if the input is to long. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You should be clearer in your requests; "I would preferably like..." is _not_ a specification! The new method is simpler than the former; see the edit...

Answer (score 0):

Per @Marged's comments, I suspect this is impossible (or at least extremely difficult) by batch file.

Here's a PowerShell solution should that be of use:

```
function Get-UserInput {
    param (
        [parameter(mandatory = $false)]
        [string]$pre='Enter text:'
        ,
        [parameter(mandatory = $false)]
        [string]$post='_'
    )
    process {
        [string]$text=''
        while ($key.Key -ne 'Enter') {
            write-host "`r$pre$text$post " -NoNewline #trailing space to hide deleted chars
            #replace the above with the 3 below if you want user input to be a different colour to the defaults 
            #write-host "`r$pre" -NoNewline
            #write-host $text -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Cyan
            #write-host "$post " -NoNewline #trailing space to hide deleted chars

            $key = [Console]::ReadKey($true)
            switch ($key.Key)
            {
                'Backspace' { $text = $text.substring(0,($text.length-1)) }
                default { $text = $text + $key.KeyChar }
            }
        }
        write-host "" #undo no new line
        write-output "$pre$text$post" 
    }
}

clear-host
$input = Get-UserInput -pre 'https://' -post '.com'
"User entered: '$input'"
```

Comment: Perhaps @Marged and you don't know Batch files enough and should not express such opinions... IMHO my Batch file solution is almost as simple as your PS one, but it performs better because in your code the cursor is _not_ placed where the input will appear and this detail is confusing for the user (I suspect is impossible (or at least extremely difficult) to correctly achieve this detail in PowerShell **`;)`**. Besides, this PS code issue an error when the Backspace key is pressed with an empty input, and it takes _much more time_ to (start) run than the Batch file solution...