# How to limit a batch variable's length

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, limit, maxlength

Is it any way to limit the length of a batch variable? I mean, if it is possible to program a variable that only admits between 0 and x characters? So, for an instance, if I entered 123456  and the max length was 4 it wouldn't proceed to continue. I hope you can understand my question.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no way for such a limit; however, you can use substring expansion like `%variable:~4%` and check whether this is empty; if not, the string length exceeds 4 characters...

Comment: Be warned: batch language is not designed for jobs as complex as the one you're apparently attempting.  That doesn't mean it can't be done, but you should seriously consider using a better designed language.  (Or, more accurately, a language that *was* designed rather than accumulating more or less at random.)

Comment: For max length of 4, `if not "%var:~4%"=="" goto ask_again`

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I _really_ would like to see a solution written in any "better designed language" that be much simpler than the pure Batch file solution [below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34466973/how-to-limit-a-batch-variables-length/34473221#34473221). Be warned: such other language solutions are frequently as complex as the pure Batch file ones, like in [this powershell example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33588233/echo-text-after-the-set-command-in-batch).

Comment: @Aacini: I'm not sure why you've made it so complex (see Mofi's answer for comparison) but if we converted your approach to C, for example, I'm confident it would be significantly simpler.  Compare the `for /F` command invoking a subshell and the NULL device you've used to generate a carriage return character with the four character C equivalent, `'\r'`.  Even in Mofi's example, compare `"%UserInput:~4%" == ""` with `strlen(userinput) > 4`.  (Be that as it may, however, I wasn't really thinking about simplicity so much as reliability and maintainability, things like structured loops vs goto.)

Comment: (I'm being somewhat hypocritical, mind you.  The project of mine I use the most at work has large chunks written in batch.  But I had specific reasons for choosing that option, and I knew what I was doing, plus I'm the only user.  In *most* cases, for a project of any size, batch is not a sensible option IMO.)  But YMMV.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I am afraid you did not read the description in my answer. Mofi's solution certainly does _not_ solve the original request: "if I entered 123456 and the max length was 4 **it wouldn't proceed to continue**"; that is: "limit the length of a batch variable".

Comment: Also, remember that this must be a solution _for the OP_, not for you or me. Explain the OP that he/she must install the C compiler and all the additional stuff in order to use your "simpler" solution...

Comment: @Aacini: I suppose you could interpret "wouldn't proceed to continue" that way, but I'd be prepared to bet that Mofi's solution does exactly what the OP wants, i.e., the batch file doesn't "proceed to continue" but stops until the user enters a suitable string.

Comment: As for *this must be a solution for the OP*, well, that's why my comment was a comment and not an answer.  But if the OP needs to do something as sophisticated as vetting the input (rather than simply trusting the user to get it right) then they're *probably* building something big and complex enough to justify the minor overhead of learning how to use an IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demonstration batch code according to suggestions of [aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl) and [rojo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1683264/rojo):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
:UserPrompt
cls
set "UserInput="
set /P "UserInput=Enter string with a length between 1 and 4: "
if not defined UserInput goto UserPrompt
if not "!UserInput:~4!" == "" goto UserPrompt
echo/
echo String entered: !UserInput!
echo/
endlocal
pause
```

`!UserInput:~4!` is replaced by command processor on execution of the batch file by the string from user input starting with fifth character. First character of a string value has index value 0 which is reason for number 4 for fifth character. This string is empty if user entered a string not longer than 4 characters, otherwise this substring is **not** empty resulting in user must input again a string.

Delayed expansion is used to avoid an exit of batch processing caused by a syntax error if the user enters a string containing an odd number of double quotes.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `cls /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "limit the length of a batch variable *when it is read via SET /P command*", then you may use the ReadLine subroutine described at [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5775&p=44274#p44274), that emulates `SET /P` command using pure Batch file commands, and just insert the maximum length restriction.

```
@echo off
setlocal

call :ReadNChars string4="Enter 4 characters maximum: " 4
echo String read: "%string4%"
goto :EOF


:ReadNChars var="prompt" maxLen

rem Read a line emulating SET /P command
rem Antonio Perez Ayala

rem Initialize variables
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo > _
for /F %%a in ('copy /Z _ NUL') do set "CR=%%a"
for /F %%a in ('echo prompt $H ^| cmd') do set "BS=%%a"

rem Show the prompt and start reading
set /P "=%~2" < NUL
set "input="
set i=0

:nextKey
   set "key="
   for /F "delims=" %%a in ('xcopy /W _ _ 2^>NUL') do if not defined key set "key=%%a"

   rem If key is CR: terminate input
   if "!key:~-1!" equ "!CR!" goto endRead

   rem If key is BS: delete last char, if any
   set "key=!key:~-1!"
   if "!key!" equ "!BS!" (
      if %i% gtr 0 (
         set /P "=!BS! !BS!" < NUL
         set "input=%input:~0,-1%"
         set /A i-=1
      )
      goto nextKey
   )

   rem Insert here any filter on the key
   if %i% equ %3 goto nextKey

   rem Else: show and accept the key
   set /P "=.!BS!%key%" < NUL
   set "input=%input%%key%"
   set /A i+=1

goto nextKey

:endRead
echo/
del _
endlocal & set "%~1=%input%"
exit /B
```

However, if you want to limit the length of a Batch variable in other cases, like `SET /A` or plain `SET` commands, then there is no way to do that. Of course, you may execute such commands and *then* cut the variable value to the maximum length, but that process is an entirely different thing.